# How can I build a nuget package from project.json?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package, .net-core

I'm looking for the easiest way of building a nuget package from my sources. I have Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and my solution has a .NET Core Class Library Project (based on project.json) . I'm trying to create a package from that project. Currently in order to be able to do so I created a .nuspec file and manually edited it, i.e. copied all dependencies listed in my project.json file.

Is there any better way other than creating and editing the .nuspec file manually? In case I make changes in the project.json I also have to reflect them in the .nuspec file which sounds odd.

BTW, This [guide](http://damien.dennehy.me/blog/2016/01/15/creating-nuget-package-3-easy-steps-using-class-library-package/) doesn't work for me because there is no 'Produce outputs on build' checkbox

[image]

Although the Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools are installed

[image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the steps we followed in our project to generate NuGet package-

1.Download `Nuget.exe` and place it in the folder where `.csproj` file exists.

2.Open cmd and type `nuget spec`. File with `.nuspec` extension will be created.

3.Open the created file and add tag:

```
<files> <file src="..\..\SomeRoot\**\*.*" target="libs\net461" /> </files>
```

4.Execute `nuget pack A.csproj –IncludeReferencedProjects` in cmd. File with `.nupkg` extension gets created.

5.Go to visual studio. In NuGet package manager settings, Add in “Package Sources” and provide path where your `.nupkg` and `.nuspec` file exists.

6.Close Nuget package manager and again open it. Now you can find it in your created package source under browse tab.

Note: Your `.nuspec` file should be like :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <metadata  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <id>ABC.XYZ.FL</id>
    <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    <title>ABC.XYZ.FL</title>
    <authors>ABC</authors>
    <owners>ABC</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Framework that will be used to create objects in XYZ world</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>2016</copyright>
    <tags>ABC.XYZ.FL</tags>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\Debug\*.dll" target="lib\net461" />
  </files>
</package>
```

The following links contains more details about creating nuget package and hosting it locally:

https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package

https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds

https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-file

See if this helps.

---

**EDIT:**

Here's dotnet pack command sample for your reference -

```
"scripts": {
  "postcompile": [
    "dotnet pack --no-build --configuration %compile:Configuration%"
  ]
}
```

Comment: There is no. csproj file. Instead, project.json is used where all dependencies are listed. My problem is that I'm looking for a way to avoid manual copying the dependencies to. nuspec file when they change.

Comment: Oh, I was right, I was missing this! Thanks. You can correct your answer then so I can accept it.

Comment: check my EDIT answer